# Запустите скрипт/команду POWERSHELL из C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

Я попытался запустить код, но получил ошибку типа времени выполнения:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using Microsoft.PowerShell;
namespace WinFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var results = ps.AddCommand().BeginInvoke();
 
                label1.Text = "";
                var R = ps.EndInvoke(results);
                foreach (var item in R)
                {
                    label1.Text = label1.Text + item.ToString();
                }
                }
                

            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            

            using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var results = ps.AddCommand("Install-Module -Name PSFalcon -Scope CurrentUser").Invoke();

                label1.Text = "";
                foreach (var h in results)
                {
                    foreach (var item in h.Properties)
                    {
                        label1.Text = label1.Text + item.MemberType;


                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

`System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException: 'Cannot load PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.PowerShell.Diagnostics because of the following error: The PowerShell snap-in module U:\Downloads\WinFormsApp1\WinFormsApp1\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics.dll does not have the required PowerShell snap-in strong name Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Diagnostics, Version=7.2.5.500, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL.'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10427230/12888024 `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` или переустановить PS и плагины на более новую версию или переустановить SDK пакет.

Comment: большое спасибо @aepot

Comment: Это сайт Windows, который не подлежит переустановке POWERSHELL на нем, потому что это довольно секретное место (компания по информационной безопасности) @aepot

Comment: Это уже вопрос к вашим безопасникам, а не к нам, в таком случае.

Comment: Я получил разрешение от своего начальства в компании

Comment: Вот еще обратите внимание https://stackoverflow.com/q/57166406/12888024

Comment: Большое спасибо, о царь!